# Xamarin forms ListView DataTemplate Label text cutting

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, itemtemplate

I am facing label cutting issue in xamarin.forms 4.0. In my listview using data template and binding data from view model. If I do text changes dynamically to the model object the lebel text is cutting. The same code was working before upgrading to xamrin.forms 4.0

Tried different HorizontalOption values, changed layouts like grid and stack but no luck.

In the below image the % completed label is cutting on few items with ellipses at the end.

Sample code can be found here  [DataTemplateTest](https://github.com/M-Narender-Reddy/MyRepo)

[image: Please find image here]

Xaml Code:

````
<StackLayout>
 <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}" 
      CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate">
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <local:CourseViewCell></local:CourseViewCell>                    
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
 </StackLayout>
```

CourseViewCell:

<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="DataTemplateTest.CourseViewCell">
 <ViewCell.View>
     <Frame  x:Name="CourseFrame"
             CornerRadius="5"
             Padding="0"
             HasShadow="True"
             IsClippedToBounds="True"               
             BackgroundColor="White">
         <Grid RowSpacing="0"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                          IsClippedToBounds="True">
                 <Image  x:Name="CourseImage"
                                              Aspect="AspectFill"
                                              HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                              VerticalOptions="Start"
                                              HeightRequest="171"
                                              Source="{Binding CourseImage}"
                                             ></Image>
             </StackLayout>
             <Label Grid.Row="1"
                    x:Name="CourseName"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    FontAttributes="None"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Text="{Binding CourseName}"
                    Margin="15,5,10,0"
                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation">

             </Label>

             <Label x:Name="CategoryName"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    FontAttributes="None"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Margin="15,0,10,0"
                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />

             <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                          Grid.Row="3"
                          HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                          Margin="5,5,10,0">
                 <Label  Text="{Binding CompletionPercentage, Converter={StaticResource PercentageToText}}"
                         FontSize="Micro"
                         FontAttributes="None"
                         TextColor="Black"
                         HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                         HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
             </StackLayout>

             <StackLayout Grid.Row="4"
                          Margin="0,12,0,0"
                          x:Name="ProgressStack"
                          HeightRequest="8"
                          Spacing="0"
                          Padding="0"
                          VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          IsClippedToBounds="True"
                          BackgroundColor="Black">
             </StackLayout>

         </Grid>
     </Frame>
 </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>


ViewModel:

public class MainViewModel : BaseModel
 {
     public MainViewModel()
     {
         ObservableCollection<Course> courseList = new ObservableCollection<Course>();

         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {
             Course course = new Course()
             {
                 CourseName = "Course " + i,
                 CategoryName = "category " + i,
                 CompletionPercentage = i,
                 CourseImage = "https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/qXrJJ-l_jMrQbARjnToD0fi-Tsg=/800x600/filters:no_upscale()/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/d6/93/d6939718-4e41-44a8-a8f3-d13648d2bcd0/c3npbx.jpg"
             };

             courseList.Add(course);
         }

         this.Courses = courseList;
     }

     private ObservableCollection<Course> courses;
     public ObservableCollection<Course> Courses
     {
         get => this.courses;
         set
         {
             this.courses = value;
             this.RaisePropertyChanged("Courses");
         }
     }
 }
````

Comment: if it worked on Xamarin.Forms before 4.0 then it is likely a bug, submit to their github

Comment: you need to increase the width of the label to accommodate the greater length of the text

Comment: Try using a ColumnDefinition and setting a Width propertythere

Comment: @IvanIčin Thank you. Yes, filed a bug here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6447

Comment: @Jason, Yes, if I give fixed width to label it is working fine but, I want the label's width to be dynamic as per the text. I need to display a tick mark image at the start of the text in case of 100% completion.

Comment: @NarenderReddy Suggest that setting `WeightRequest` for label or stacklayout.Then you can set background color to `StackLayout` and `Label`, this will help check where problem is .And if possible, you can show screenshot with background color in question later.

Answer (score 2):

1.Remove the outer `StackLayout` of the Label.

2.Remove the `HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"`. Not sure why this is creating the problem in latest Xamarin.Forms 4.0. But in your case, this is not required.

So, your Label should look like this:

```
<Label Grid.Row="3"
       Margin="5,5,10,0"
       Text="{Binding CompletionPercentage, Converter={StaticResource PercentageToText}}"
       FontSize="Micro"
       FontAttributes="None"
       TextColor="Black"
       HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Great! it works without stack layout but, I need the stack layout to show a tick mark image in place of 100% (in case of 100 % completion the design would be the tick mark and the text  " Completed"). So, its not just a label but image and label inside stack layout.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove this code:
LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"

Comment: If the LineBreakMode is removed, the second word in the label is not visible for few items on scroll down. i.e only the percent value ( 2%, 3% etc) is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think the margin of the outer stack layout is causing the issue for truncation for dynamic text. Its horizontal option should be FillAndExpand and instead of margin, you should set padding on it. Also since it's a single child (the complete percent label) you should use a ContentView instead.

Try -

1. Remove the outer stack layout of the label
2. Use only the label without the text alignment options

   `<Label  Text="{Binding CompletionPercentage, Converter={StaticResource PercentageToText}}"
   FontSize="Micro"
   TextColor="Black"
   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
   VerticalOptions="Center"/>`

Comment: Tried removing the outer stack layout and removed alignment options like this
<Label  Grid.Row="3"  Text="{Binding CompletionPercentage, Converter={StaticResource PercentageToText}}"
                            FontSize="Micro"
                            FontAttributes="None"
                            TextColor="Black"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                            />
Same issue, not change in the view.

Answer (score 0):

In the Listview containing the label give it MinimumWidthRequest="300" or a commensurate width.  I had the same problem and that's how I solved it. The listview was not expanding to accommodate.